# Are there nontrivial rational solutions to $\sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2} = \sqrt{1-z^2}$?

Tags: number-theory

Obviously $(a,0,a)$,$(-a,0,a)$,$(0,a,a)$,$(0,-a,a)$ are solutions.

I tried finding solutions brute-forcing this problem, but I discovered there are no solutions with numerator and denominator smaller than 100'000.

I can prove that the question is equivalent to finding a bunch of natural numbers that satisfy:

$x'^2+ka^2 = w^2\\y'^2+kb^2 = w^2\\z'^2+kc^2 = w^2\\a+b=c$

(here is $x=x'/w$, $y=y'/w$, $z=z'/w$)

It can be proven they are equivalent as follows:

To go from the title to the 4 equations:

1. Call $w$ the lcm of the denominators of x, y, z
2. Define $x'=xw$, $y'=yw$, $z'=zw$
3. The equation is now $\sqrt{w^2-x^2} + \sqrt{w^2-y^2} = \sqrt{w^2-z^2}$
4. This equation can only hold if all sqrt are natural numbers, up to a common factor $k$ by [this theorem](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/)
5. Now call $a=\sqrt{w^2-x^2}/\sqrt{k}$, $b=\sqrt{w^2-y^2}/\sqrt{k}$, $c=\sqrt{w^2-z^2}/\sqrt{k}$
6. The original equation becomes $a+b=c$, the other 3 can be calculated by the definitions of the previous step.

To go from the 4 equations to the title:

1. Rewrite the first 3 equations to $a=\sqrt{w^2-x^2}/\sqrt{k}$, $b=\sqrt{w^2-y^2}/\sqrt{k}$, $c=\sqrt{w^2-z^2}/\sqrt{k}$
2. Plug in in equation 4.
3. Substitude $x=x'/w$, $y=y'/w$, $z=z'/w$

But apparently being able to split a number into two squares in at least three different ways, is quite a rare property, so I would suspect that finding three with the extra property that $a+b=c$ is probably impossible, which makes me believe that there are no solutions, or that solutions are very rare.

But is there a way to find a solution, or prove that non exists except for the trivial case?

Edit: Added proof of equivalence.

Comment: what are $a$ and $b$

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: @marlasca23 I used that method to generate Pythagorean triples in the brute force approach. But I am unsure as to how I can use them analytically.

Comment: @DietrichBurde a,b,c,x',y',z' and w are natural numbers (so positive integers).

Comment: I guess the sign of x,y,z doesn't really matter, as they are squared for every occurrence. But the signs of a,b, and c do matter, cause we are taking the positive roots in the original question. @DietrichBurde

Comment: Would you be interested in solutions where $x,y,z$ are rational, but $a,b,c$ are not but have a common factor $\sqrt k$ ?

Comment: @Empy2 I guess that also works? It seems to also reduce to the title equation. I'll edit the question

Comment: Are you looking for solutions $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ or in $\mathbb Q^3$?

Comment: @A.G. $\mathbb{Q}^3$. Solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are quite trivial.

Comment: there are lots with k not equal to 1, for example $\sqrt{14^2-13^2}+\sqrt{14^2-11^2}=\sqrt{14^2-2^2}$

Comment: *"apparently being able to split a number into two squares in at least three different ways, is quite a rare property"* You can easily generate such numbers using the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity): $$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2) = (ax\pm by)^2 + (ay\mp bx)^2$$ And since every prime of the form $4n+1$ can be written as the sum of 2 squares, you can generate a number that's the sum of 2 squares in $2^{k-1}$ ways by multiplying $k$ such primes together. Eg, $5\cdot 13\cdot 17 = 1105 = 4^2+33^2 = 9^2+32^2 = 12^2+31^2 = 23^2+24^2$

Comment: I don't know if that will help solve your problem. But here's some [Python code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkNFuwyAMRd_5Cj8Cc6Ul21OlfoxRoENK0w2IBH8_G6JGql8iXx9frrP4AC5ocgi1masCLkJwcANyvasIjbvaelc-ZWIrfICzDRnKmmyDC7fVDGTqy6LXrjfDHDOyUjuSfNnTxmbItFILh8h_eX9kbSnd85Hjx9OCYAvFVRx50OUYQKTBSIVnggJxe3nI2JxzqRb9ukBIz4ecO5zLyOvX7E94gAK8cmn5IYffkZws9XOcUu-v6wlnPljP-CWfCb_Nsfub4lZ0we5pizH_QZJjQg==&lang=python) which implements the above identity for any number of input pairs.

Comment: Obviously, for any solution $(x,y,z), (\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)$ is also a solution, so you should just restrict the problem to $x, y, z \ge 0$. The trivials solutions are then $(1, a,a), (a,1,a)$, not $0$ as you've said.

Comment: FWIW there seems to be a solution for $k=3,w=12n+2$ so long as $w$ contains no prime factor of the form $6m-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to generate solutions for $k=3$.

It is well known that every number whose prime factors are all of the form $6m+1$, is also of the form $n=a^2+3b^2$.  Then
$$(2n)^2=4a^4+24a^2b^2+36b^4\\
=(2a^2-6b^2)^2+3(4ab)^2\\
=(a^2+6ab-3b^2)^2+3(a^2-2ab-3b^2)^2\\
=(a^2-6ab-3b^2)^2+3(a^2+2ab-3b^2)^2$$
Note two of the unsquared left-hand terms add up to the third, and two of the unsquared right-hand terms add up to the third.

There are also solutions for $k$ not equal to 3.